# How does Angular handle non-imported modules from Angular libraries?

Tags: angular, node-modules, ivy, angular-library

I'm currently running an Angular 12 application and importing some Angular libraries into it.

Now, let's say I'm importing a heavy angular library, `ng add huge-sized-library`, and this library exports a lot of Angular Modules.

How does import only one **small** module from the heavy library will affect the application size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the modules that you import will be included in the application build. The other modules will not be used in the build or removed by *tree shaking*.

For example, the ng-bootstrap library [is setup in this way](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#imports).

Whether this works correctly might depend on the setup of the library. You can check which modules are actually included in the build by using [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) or similar tools. You need to add the `--stats-json` option to `ng build` to generate the required input for these tools.